# canvaskit-wasm: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'href')

Tags: cloudflare-workers, canvaskit

I was looking for a library compatible with the web's Canvas API that I could use with Cloudflare Workers and found canvaskit-wasm.
However, when I try to use it, I am stuck with the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'href')`.

Minimum reproduction method:
`src/server.js`

```js
import CanvasKitInit from "canvaskit-wasm";
import { Hono } from "hono";
const app = new Hono();
const CanvasKit = await CanvasKitInit();

app.get("/", (c) => c.text("Hello!"));

export default app;
```

`wrangler.toml`

```ini
name = "canvaskit-test"
main = "src/server.js"
compatibility_date = "2022-07-12"
node_compat = true
```